# Randomise list of words in variable

Tags: php, variables, random, shuffle

I have variable which is list of words separated by comma like this:

```
$word_list = "word1, word2, word3, word4, word5";
```

Word list can contain more or less words than in example above.

How to randomise `$word_list` to get something like this:

> word1, word5, word2, word3, word4

or

> word4, word5, word3, word1, word2

Comment: See `explode()` and `shuffle()`

Comment: [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, convert it to an array (using [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)),  [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the array and then [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it back to a string:

```
$word_list = 'word1, word2, word3, word4, word5';
$word_arr  = explode(', ', $word_list);
shuffle( $word_arr );
$rand_list = implode(', ', $word_arr);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/889558)

Answer (score 1):

You can first `explode` the string into an array, then `shuffle` it, and then convert it back to a `string`.

Something in the lines of this:

```
$word_array = explode(',', $word_list);
shuffle($word_array);
$shuffeled_word_list = implode(',', $word_array);
```

Comment: This will result in some odd whitespace.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Yes, like @BenM said, it will not add whitespace in front of word1 (if that word is not on first place). I will work arount that.

Comment: Ah yes it should've been ```', '``` instead of ```','```, sorry for that.